# How do I sort an object from an array and print the entire sorted array?

Tags: java

I want to sort the Weight object of the array and then I want to print the whole sorted array, how can I do it?

The organize() method I don't know how to do it so that it can sort the array, I can't use Print since these are used in the test.

**Animal class**

```
package model;

public class Animal {
    private String name;
    private double weight;
    private String  classification;
    
    public Animal(String nam, double wei,  String classi) {
        name = nam;
        weight = wei;
        classification = classi;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    
    public String getClassification(){
        return classification;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Animal: " + name + ", Peso: " + weight + "Kg, " + "De tipo: " + classification + " \n";
    }
    
    
}
```

**Zoo Class**

```
package model;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Zoo {
    private Animal[] animals;

    public Zoo() {
        animals = new Animal[50];
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
        boolean inserted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.length && !inserted; i++) {
            if (animals[i] == null) {
                animals[i] = animal;
                inserted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public Animal organize() {
        
    
    }

    public double calculateAverage() {
        double avg = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
            if (animals[i] != null) {
                avg = avg + animals[i].getWeight();
                cont++;
            }
        }
        avg = avg / cont;
        return avg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animales:\n" + Arrays.toString(animals);
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import model.Animal;
import model.Zoo;

public class Test {
    private Scanner console;
    private Zoo zoo;

    public Test() {
        console = new Scanner(System.in);
        zoo = new Zoo();
    }

    public void run() {
        showMenu();
    }

    public void readData() {
        Animal animal = readAnimal();
        zoo.addAnimal(animal);
    }

    public Animal readAnimal() {
        String name = "";
        double weight = 0;
        String classification = ""; 
        System.out.println("Ingrese el animal");
        name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el peso del animal en Kg");
        weight = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo del animal (mamifero,anfibio, etc)");
        classification = console.nextLine();
        Animal animal = new Animal(name, weight, classification);
        return animal;
    }

    public void showMenu() {
        
        int option = 0;
        do {
            String menu = "MENU PRINCIPAL\n\n1. Ingresar animal\n2. Organizar los animales por peso\n3. Busqueda de un grupo de animales por tipo\n4. Ver la informacion\n5. Hallar el promedio de peso de los animales ingresados\n6. Salir";
            System.out.println(menu);
            System.out.print("Digite la opcion: ");
            option = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                readData();
                break;
            case 2:
                    System.out.println("Los animales ordenados: ");
                
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Aun no terminado");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println(zoo);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("El promedio de peso de los animales ingresados es: " + zoo.calculateAverage() + " kg.");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("Opcion no valida, intente de nuevo");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        } while (option != 6);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

MAIN MENU

1. Enter animal
2. Organize animals by weight
3. Search for a group of animals by type.
4. View information
5. Find the average weight of the animals entered.
6. Exit
   Type the option:
   When option 1 is given it executes the following.

Enter the animal

Dog

Enter the weight of the animal in Kg

20

Enter the type of animal (mammal,amphibian, etc)

Mammal

I tried using an array.sort but I couldn't figure out how to print it, I also tried using for cycles but I couldn't print it either.

Comment: One way to get `Arrays.sort` to work is to use the [`Comparable` Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).  `public class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {`. That requires you to add a `compareTo (Animal beast)` method.  Another way is to use one of the `Arrays.sort` methods that take a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) as parameter.

Comment: where are you sorting? Please add the code for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the array in place, this is how you could do that:

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparing(Animal::getWeight));
```

If you instead wanted to create a new array that was sorted by weight, you could use Java streams:

```
sortedAnimals = Arrays.stream(animals).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getWeight)).toArray(Animal[]::new);
```

In either case, to print the resulting array, just iterate over it:

```
for (Animal a : animals)
    System.out.print(a);
```

Result

```
Animal: Snake, Peso: 40.0Kg, De tipo: reptile 
Animal: Dog, Peso: 200.0Kg, De tipo: mammal 
Animal: Zebra, Peso: 350.0Kg, De tipo: mammal 
Animal: Jiraffe, Peso: 450.0Kg, De tipo: mammal
```

Comment: Why stream when you can [sort in place](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)?

Comment: Yeah.  When I started, I wasn't sure if the OP wanted a new array or not.

Comment: The method would be done in the zoo class, right? how do I print the result in the test class? i.e. how do I call the method to be able to print it in the test class?

Comment: You could add a `getAnimals` method to Zoo that just returns the array:  `public Animal[] getAnimals() { return animals; }`